# Twitter intent redirect to mobile.twitter.com

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, mobile, twitter

I am currently working on a project where we are able to share via twitter or facebook.

When I am working with twitter share, I found out twitter intent is the best way.
But I found a problem when I try to share via twitter using mobile device.

Here is my sample code:

```
var width  = 640,
    height = 440,
    left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
    top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
    url    = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Congrats!&hashtags=labmate!',

    opts   = 'status=1' +
             ',width='  + width  +
             ',height=' + height +
             ',top='    + top    +
             ',left='   + left;

window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);
```

if user already login, nothing is wrong, but when the user is not login twitter will show login form, and if the user misstype either the username or the password, twitter will redirect it to another page.

Here is the problem, after twitter redirect to another page, the url change into

https://**mobile.twitter.com**/login/error?username_or_email=sample%40mail.com&redirect_after_login=%2Fintent%2Ftweet%3Ftext%3DCongrats.......

when user finally login with the right username and password, twitter will redirect to

https://mobile.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Congrats

which is doesn't exist

What can I do? Much appreciate.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: it is just simple twitter share code using web intent

Comment: @JeremyHaile I had mentioned the problem to Twitter Dev Support, but no respond